# protobuf, dose release_* method cause memory leak in a funcation?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

code:

```
bool Client::send(main_pack* pack) {
    OnlinePackReq request;
    request.set_allocated_body(pack);

    OnlinePackResp response;
    bool send_ret = _sender->send_packet(request, response);

    pack = request.release_body();

    return send_ret;
}
```

I have to add `pack` to `request` before send data by rpc.

When I call  `request.set_allocated_body(pack);`, `request` has owership of `pack`.To return owership to old ower, I have to call `request.release_body();`.

But since `pack` is just a local variable, does it cause memory leak?

Comment: nope, pack is a pointer and its owner is out of the scope of this function, so calling release_body() does not cause any memory leak, as long as you manage the pointer pack after calling method send()

Comment: You can always run your code with valgrind just to be sure.